# Execute fork processes simultaneously

Tags: c, linux, shell, process

I am working on make basic shell in C.

Each line may contain multiple commands separated with the `;` character. Each of the commands separated by a `;` should be run simultaneously, or concurrently. (I know this is different behavior than standard Linux shells.) After that, the shell should not print the next prompt or take more input until all of these commands have finished executing. For example, the following lines are all valid and have reasonable commands specified:

```
prompt>
prompt> ls
prompt> /bin/ls
prompt> ls -l
prompt> ls -l ; cat file
prompt> ls -l ; cat file ; grep foo file2
```

For example, on the last line, the commands `ls -l`, `cat file` and `grep foo file2` should all be running at the same time.

I can split line with my splitLine function.

````
```// Function to split a line into constituent commands
char **splitLine(char *line)
{
    char **tokens = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 64);
    char *token;
    int pos = 0, bufsize = 64;
    if (!tokens)
    {
        printf("\nBuffer Allocation Error.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    token = strtok(line, " ");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", token);
        if (!strcmp(token, ";"))
        {
            tokens[pos] = NULL;
        }else
        {
            tokens[pos] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(token) + 1));
            strcpy(tokens[pos], token);
        }
        
        pos ++;
        if (pos >= bufsize)
        {
            bufsize += 64;
            line = realloc(line, bufsize * sizeof(char *));
            if (!line)
            {
                printf("\nBuffer Allocation Error.");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return tokens;
}```
````

But I don't know how to execute all commands simultaneously. And this is my execute function.

```
// Function to create child process and run command
int myShellLaunch(char **args)
{

    pid_t pid, wpid;
    int status;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // The Child Process
        if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1)
        {
            perror("myShell: ");
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (pid < 0)
    {
        //Forking Error
        perror("myShell: ");
    }
    else
    {
        // The Parent Process
        do 
        {
            wpid = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
        } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: So..  `wpid = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);` don't wait on them?

Comment: Study for inspiration the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or of [sash](https://github.com/MurphyMc/sash)... Read [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) then [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

Comment: More precisely, do not wait on the commands in the `myShellLaunch()` function.  You need it to allow each of the commands to run, and then the calling code will wait for the three child processes to finish before continuing.  Since you've not shown the code that calls either `splitLine()` or `myShellLaunch()`, we can only give hand-waving advice.  You should create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: You are likely to need to know which processes your shell started for the command line — at least once you've got background processes too (classically terminated by an `&`).  You may want to modify `myShellLaunch()` to return the PID of the child process.  Also, there is no need to test the return value of `execvp()` — if it returns, it failed; if it succeeds, it does not return.

Comment: Your notation `cmd1; cmd2; cmd3` is analogous to the standard shell notation `(cmd1 & cmd2 & cmd3 & wait)` — with the difference being that you don't start a sub-shell which launches the three commands.  That's necessary in a standard shell to avoid waiting on background processes from the main shell to complete.

Comment: I found a topic. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603612/fork-and-exec-multiple-processes-simultaneously) Can this topic help me? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Yes — that question is an almost exact duplicate of what you're asking.  The notation is the same; the requirement for concurrent execution is the same.  The answer doesn't cover waiting for the child processes to complete, but the question is about the same unusual shell-like notation.  Maybe the OP there was in the same class you're in now, only 4 years ago.